# pgcli error with m1 , I can't run pgcli on commandline but got error

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, apple-m1

Before i got this error.
I try to install pgcli package on my m1 and run it for run pgcli after i run docker follow this command

```
docker run -it \
  -e POSTGRES_USER="root" \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="root" \
  -e POSTGRES_DB="ny_taxi" \
  -v $(pwd)/ny_taxi_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/pg_data \
  -p 5001:5002 \
  postgres:13
```

```
pip3 install pgcli
```

and run

```
pgcli
```

on commandline please help.

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/pgcli", line 5, in <module>
    from pgcli.main import cli
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgcli/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pgspecial.namedqueries import NamedQueries
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgspecial/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import iocommands
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgspecial/iocommands.py", line 9, in <module>
    import psycopg
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import pq  # noqa: F401 import early to stabilize side effects
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg/pq/__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    import_from_libpq()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg/pq/__init__.py", line 106, in import_from_libpq
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: no pq wrapper available.
Attempts made:
- couldn't import psycopg 'c' implementation: No module named 'psycopg_c'
- couldn't import psycopg 'binary' implementation: No module named 'psycopg_binary'
- couldn't import psycopg 'python' implementation: libpq library not found```

I try to run pgcli on mac m1 , after i run pgcli i should got this comment
````

password for alexay

```
follow this tutorial 
[data-engineer-zoomcamp](https://youtu.be/2JM-ziJt0WI?list=PL3MmuxUbc_hJed7dXYoJw8DoCuVHhGEQb&t=457)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (Apple M1 Pro, macOD Venturs 13.6.3)

```
pip install "psycopg[binary,pool]"
```